# Append programmatically current anchor/hash/fragment to any form action url with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, anchor

I have a `JSP` with some external API custom `taglibs` that handle URLs with `hash` (I know serverside does not handle them per se).

I am trying something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').prop('action').append(window.locator.anchor)
});
```

But I am doing it wrong and I am not sure if it is the best way anyway. Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to do this because the hash is never sent to the server. But here is how you *could* do it:

```
$('form').prop('action', function(i, val) {
    return val + window.location.hash;
});
```

There are a couple of things which are not correct in your code:

- [`.prop(name)` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) *returns* the value of that property which is often a string.
- [`.append` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is a jQuery method to append a *DOM element* to another element. It is *not* a string method and cannot be used to concatenate strings.
- `window.locator.anchor` does not exist. [`window.location`  *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) holds information about the current URL and it has a property `hash` which refers to the fragment identifier of the URL.

I recommend to have a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page). It has examples for each method. You also have to [learn some elementare JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) to be able to perform simple operations such as string concatenation.

Comment: Thank You! I was going to use some custom taglibs that handle the anchor but now I realized that obviously these taglibs are converted to plain html in client side so they only handle the referor if the var is in server side. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Finally is going to be useful in another way. Thank you for correcting my mistakes!